Angular Pagination using BehaviorSubject and scan
I've been trying to create a pagination.
The HTTP call should be triggered:

when the formular has been changed (starting from page zero),
when "Load More" button is pressed  (button triggers BehaviorSubject loadMore$).

Whenever the button is pressed, new value is emitted with the current count of the results (resultCount). With the help of resultCount I can set the new page number.
Pagination:
pageSize: 10,
resultCount: 0 page will be 0;
but if I trigger load with button:
resultCount: 10, page will be 1
For the merging data from previous http call and current http call I use scan operator, which works also fine.
The problem starts, when I load multiple pages for the same form value and then change the form value again. loadMore$ is not set to 0 and it starts searching from the previous resultCount.
STEPS

Change the person type to Natural (has only 3 results)
Change the person type to different value (with more results, where we can trigger pagination)
Trigger pagination (resultCount will be set to 10)
Change the person type back to Natural
BehaviorSubject does not reset its value, so resultCount is still 10, nothing shows up, as we only have 3 results and we're asking for page 2 (or simply ignoring first 10 results)
click on the button will fix the problem as it will set resultCount to 0

Bug simulation with the description
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  Observable,
  merge,
  debounceTime,
  switchMap,
  filter,
  of,
  tap,
  scan,
  map,
} from 'rxjs';
import { PersonTypeModel } from './model/person-type.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class DropdownBasicDemo implements OnInit {
  // separate formGroup as we want to add debounceTime only for subGroup
  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    personType: new FormControl<number | null>(null, Validators.required),
    subGroup: new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      surname: new FormControl(''),
      identificationNumber: new FormControl(''),
    }),
  });

  readonly pageSize = 10;
  result$!: Observable<{ data: PersonTypeModel[]; totalRecords: number }>;
  loadMore$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  get formControls() {
    return this.formGroup.controls;
  }
  readonly personTypeOptions = [
    { label: 'Firefighter', id: 1 },
    { label: 'Policeman', id: 2 },
    { label: 'Legal', id: 3 },
    { label: 'Natural', id: 4 },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    const personTypeChange$ = this.formControls.personType.valueChanges.pipe(
      tap(() => this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity()) // update value and validity (without this will be first change mark as invalid)
    );

    // combine two observables
    this.result$ = merge(
      personTypeChange$,
      this.formControls.subGroup.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300))
    ).pipe(
      filter(() => this.formGroup.valid), // person type is required, check
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.loadMore$.pipe(
          switchMap((resultCount) => {
            return this.getPersonByPersonType(resultCount);
          }),
          scan(
            (state, change) => ({
              ...state,
              ...change,
              data: [...(state?.data ?? []), ...(change?.data ?? [])],
            }) // scan previous and current result
          )
        );
      }),
      map((state) => ({
        ...state,
        noMoreRecords: state.totalRecords === state.data.length,
      }))
    );
  }

<form
  [formGroup]="formGroup"
  class="card flex flex-column gap-3 justify-content-center"
>
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="personTypeOptions"
    optionValue="id"
    placeholder="Select person type"
    formControlName="personType"
  />

  <div class="flex gap-3" formGroupName="subGroup">
    <input pInputText placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" type="text" />
    <input
      pInputText
      formControlName="surname"
      placeholder="Surname"
      type="text"
    />
    <input
      pInputText
      formControlName="identificationNumber"
      placeholder="Identification number"
      type="text"
    />
  </div>
</form>

<div *ngIf="result$ | async as result" class="flex flex-column gap-3">
  <div *ngFor="let personType of result?.data">
    {{ personType.name }} {{ personType.surname }} - {{ personType.description
    }}
  </div>

  <button
    pButton
    (click)="loadMore$.next(result?.data?.length)"
    [disabled]="result.noMoreRecords"
  >
    Load More
  </button>
</div>


Here is the simplified stackblitz demo
I've tried to fix the problem by emitting new value whenever form changed this.loadMore$.next(0)
and adding debounceTime(1) to this.loadMore$ stream to prevent duplicit HTTP calls.
Here is an updated example
It works, but maybe there is a better solution how to reset behavior subject. Or maybe even create stream in completely different way.
Thanks for any advices!
